# How can I make the active MacVim tab more obvious in fullscreen mode?

Tags: vim, macvim

When I use MacVim normally and have multiple tabs open, it's easy to see which tab is active because it's much lighter than the others.

However, in fullscreen mode, they are all the lighter color and I can't see which is active.

Is there any setting I can change to make this more obvious?

Comment: No, there's no setting for that. You could file a bug, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

As @romainl pointed out there is no way to do that form within MacVim.  However you may want to play around with the Mac OS X colour schemes which will change the colour of your active tab.

On Mountain Lion there is only blue and graphite:
[image]

I would look around on the web for a third party plugin that provides you with some more themes.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using non-GUI tabs:

```
set guioptions-=e
```

This renders tabs in the main content window using text, somewhat like the status line. See `:help go-e` and `:help tabline`. You can then customize the colors of the tabs with your colorscheme using the `TabLine`, `TabLineFill`, and `TabLineSel` highlighting groups. These tabs are compatible with the mouse.